# 2 by 2 subfigures array in a 2 column document

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have a figure that contains 4 subfigure. What I want, is to arrange then as a 2 by 2 array in a single column of a 2 column document, thus not in the whole A4 page.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PWM_with_DK}
    \caption{PWM of Motor 1 with no anti-derivative kick logic implemented}
    \label{PWM_with_DK}
\end{subfigure}
~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
  %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{GameRV_with_DK}
    \caption{The set point Yaw angle with no anti-derivative kick logic implemented}
    \label{GameRV_with_DK}
\end{subfigure}
~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
%(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PWM_anti_DK}
    \caption{PWM of Motor 1 with anti-derivative kick logic implemented}
    \label{PWM_anti_DK}
\end{subfigure}
~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
%(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{GameRV_anti_DK}
    \caption{The set point Yaw angle with anti-derivative kick logic implemented}
    \label{PWM_anti_DK}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Anti-Derivative Kick effect}\label{fig:animals}
\end{figure}
```

But what I got is as shown in the image.

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try replacing `\textwidth` with `\linewidth`.

Comment: Which subfigure package are you using?  There are several, and all are just glorified minipages.

Comment: @Bernard thanks a lot, this helped. I think with some few modifications on the code I might get it as needed.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am using `\usepackage{subcaption}`

Answer (score 3):

Note: almost any line which ends with `}` will have a space added to the end (the `~` also adds space).  This enables the line to break at this point, but it also adds a small amount to the line width.  In other words, `\columnwidth` plus 1 space is too big for one line.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength{\tempdima}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{PWM of Motor 1 with no anti-derivative kick logic implemented}
    \label{PWM_with_DK}
\end{subfigure}
~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
  %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{The set point Yaw angle with no anti-derivative kick logic implemented}
    \label{GameRV_with_DK}
\end{subfigure}
~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
%(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{PWM of Motor 1 with anti-derivative kick logic implemented}
    \label{PWM_anti_DK}
\end{subfigure}
~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
%(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{The set point Yaw angle with anti-derivative kick logic implemented}
    \label{PWM_anti_DK}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Anti-Derivative Kick effect}\label{fig:animals}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```